MIP SDK error Failed API call: profile_add_engine_async Failed
I am developing using MIP SDK,
but the following error is occurring:
why not find url ?
https://dataservice.protection.outlook.com/PsorWebService/v1/ClientSyncFile/MipPolicies/ScrubbedEmail

can who tell me the cause?
Thanks.
Error   2024-07-18 10:36:40.790 policy_profile_impl.cpp:522 w3wp (13032)    "Failed API call: profile_add_engine_async Failed with: [NetworkError: 'Policy sync failed, NetworkError.Category=FailureResponseCode, HttpResponse.StatusCode=404, HttpRequest.SanitizedUrl=https://dataservice.protection.outlook.com/PsorWebService/v1/ClientSyncFile/MipPolicies/ScrubbedEmail, HttpRequest.Id={F6F44A48-47FF-4B1F-94B0-A04B6990BE0E}, CorrelationId=b2356790-403d-4cc6-921c-a74f665090d9, CorrelationId.Description=PolicyProfile']"   mipns::ProfileImpl::AddEngineAsync  23820
Trace   2024-07-18 10:36:40.790 default_task_dispatcher_delegate.cpp:83 w3wp (13032)    "Executing task 'ApiFailure-14438' on a new detached thread"    mipns::DefaultTaskDispatcherDelegate::ExecuteTaskOnIndependentThread    23820
Info    2024-07-18 10:36:40.790 policy_profile_impl.cpp:522 w3wp (13032)    "Ended API task: profile_add_engine_async"  mipns::ProfileImpl::AddEngineAsync  23820
Info    2024-07-18 10:36:40.790 oneds_helper.cpp:532    w3wp (13032)    "OneDsHelper::WriteTelemetryEvent(profile_add_engine_async)"    mipns::OneDSHelper::WriteTelemetryEvent 23820
Info    2024-07-18 10:36:40.790 diagnostic_utils.cpp:80 w3wp (13032)    "Send Telemetry. Event Name : [profile_add_engine_async]
    App.ApplicationId: [3062cd3c-2af4-4f73-9c2e-eb95b3d10d21], Pii: [None]
    App.ApplicationName: [Easy MIP Connector - Dev], Pii: [None]
    App.ApplicationVersion: [1.0.0.0], Pii: [None]
    App.SessionId: [], Pii: [None]
    Engine.SessionId: [], Pii: [None]
    Event.CorrelationId: [b2356790-403d-4cc6-921c-a74f665090d9], Pii: [None]
    Event.CorrelationIdDescription: [PolicyProfile], Pii: [None]
    Event.Duration: [4.68965], Pii: [None]
    Event.ErrorType: [NetworkError], Pii: [None]
    Event.Failed.File: [src\upe\api_impl\policy_profile_impl.cpp], Pii: [None]
    Event.Failed.Func: [mipns::ProfileImpl::AddEngineAsync], Pii: [None]
    Event.Failed.Line: [522], Pii: [None]
    Event.Failed.Message: [Failed API call: profile_add_engine_async Failed with: [NetworkError: 'Policy sync failed, NetworkError.Category=FailureResponseCode, HttpResponse.StatusCode=404, HttpRequest.SanitizedUrl=https://dataservice.protection.outlook.com/PsorWebService/v1/ClientSyncFile/MipPolicies/ScrubbedEmail, HttpRequest.Id={F6F44A48-47FF-4B1F-94B0-A04B6990BE0E}']], Pii: [None]
    Event.UniqueId: [744c49a1-88cf-4145-a8f0-8c7e919d6075], Pii: [None]
    EventInfo.Level: [10], Pii: [None]
    EventInfo.PrivTags: [33554432], Pii: [None]
    MIP.Version: [1.15.86], Pii: [None]
    MipContext.EventId: [c3a4ab57-25db-4948-afb7-9daaa6e27f59], Pii: [None]
    iKey: [ce9aa5fb5a414ecebb15af10715bd8ff-831d197e-fc97-4df6-b998-c8c13a0fc3ce-6768], Pii: [None]
"   mipns::WriteTelemetryEventToLog 23820

